# copy Multiple values from multiple input fields into one input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to copy the value of multiple input fields into 1 single input field.

currently I can only copy 1 input field into another one using the following code:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('inputName'), 'keyup', function () {
   document.getElementById('inputURL').value = this.value.replace(' ', ' ');
 $(".sect2 input[@value='']").parents(".secTxt").hide();
});


function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);
  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);
}
```

is it possible to do something like this:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('inputName, inputName2, inputName3, inputName4'), 'keyup', function () {
   document.getElementById('inputURL').value = this.value.replace(' ', ' ');
 $(".sect2 input[@value='']").parents(".secTxt").hide();
});


function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);
  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);
}
```

if not, what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

None of the examples bellow works and neither they are practical.

I also tried my own solution and that didn't work either.

I can only assume this is not possible using javascript!

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Also, why `.replace(' ', ' ')`?

Comment: @Johan, not sitting on my desk at the moment. but i thought I better ask and get an answer/solution for it before I start working on it.

Comment: and i think you should use jquery that is way better.

Comment: @user3454730 It is easily achievable but we can't see all of your code  , we can provide examples and help and then the rest is up to you. What exactly is my example not doing? You've used jQuery in your example so I presumed you've got this referenced in your files to use? also how do you want to concatenate all the values into one input? i.e comma separated or by space?

Comment: @MarkWalters, never mind mate. I found a solution for it.. I will post my own solution and will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @user3454730 charming, i've updated my solution and added a fiddle anyway, i've made a few assumptions as I don't have all the facts.

Comment: @MarkWalters, whats with the sarcasm?! I said I figured it out anyway. I will post my answer once stackoverflow allows me. I wasn't trying to be rude or anything! I tried your solution first time and it didn't work for me. your assumption was right. I am suing jquery as well but that doesn't change the fact that your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: `Sorry, but this doesn't do anything. it doesn't even work for 1 let alone "Multiple"` <- this is sarcasm. At the end of the day i'm trying to help you, and with limited information i.e no HTML, no context, no clue as to what you are trying to achieve there is only so much I can do. Anyway I am glad you found an answer and welcome to SO. Please have a look here for some tips and info on posting questions etc. - http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Your second example isn't possible, but if you're using jQuery anyway then something like this is probably the simplest solution

**UPDATE** - Having thought about this, you probably want something like below

```
$(function(){
   $('#inputName, #inputName2, #inputName3, #inputName4').keyup(function(){    
       var str = "";
       $('#inputName, #inputName2, #inputName3, #inputName4').each(function() {
           str += $(this).val().replace(' ', '');
       });
       $('#inputURL').val(str);
   });
});
```

I've added a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfphM/) of a working example

Comment: why the first two `inputNames` have `#` sign and the rest don't?

Comment: I forgot to put them in :). Edited

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't do anything. it doesn't even work for 1 let alone "Multiple".

Comment: I was wanting to do a "first name" + "last name" => "usersname" technique and this worked for that, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

insetead of `document.getElementById()` you can use `document.querySelector()`:

```
document.querySelector('#inputName, #inputName2, #inputName3, #inputName4')
```

Comment: Assuming he's not using IE7 ;)

Comment: hmm...@johan agreed with you, won't work in older version of ie.